Hisense beverage refrigerator not cooling
I have a Hisense beverage refrigerator (HBC54D6AS) that isn't working. If I unplug it for a while and plug it back in, the lights and control panel will come on, but it isn't cooling. I had originally thought the compressor is bad, but from reading comments on another unanswered question on here, I'm wondering if it's the thermostat? I didn't see that as a part I could order though.
Any tips for how to troubleshoot would be appreciated.

It is possible it is just the thermostat.. Does the compressor gets power ?

I actually tried it again just now and I did hear a compressor click and stuff happening. I don't believe I heard that last time, but maybe I just missed it.

It might be the run/start capacitor for the compressor.  You will need a multi meter to run tests.  Replacing stuff till it runs right can get expensive without testing.  Google/your favourite search might find a service manual for that model.

New data point. It did start up and cool down and run for a while. Then I came back to it a few hours later and it was shut off completely (no light when I open the door even)

check out Solución de problemas in https://assets.hisense-usa.com/assets/ProductDownloads/273/e3bb226c39/20200522-3-Beverage-cooler-user-manual.pdf

The compressor does not start immediately after changing the temperature setting - This is normal, no error has occurred - The compressor starts after a
period of time.

